# grid-auto-flow: column cannot catch child div width with percentage value

Tags: css, css-grid

I want to use the CSS grid property to put the line and some span tags horizontally and flexibly like the below capture.

[image]

Actually, the easiest way is using CSS flex property with gap property but the old ios version cannot allow gap property.

So I used `grid-auto-flow: column;` but because of this property, the width of the child tag cannot work well.

```
import styled from "styled-components";

export const Container = styled.div`
  width: 375px;
  display: grid;
  /* grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr); */
  grid-auto-columns: auto;
  place-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
`;

export const Flex = styled.div`
  width: 375px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
`;

export const LineWithPercentage = styled.div`
  width: 42%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
`;

export const LineWithPX = styled.div`
  width: 164px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
`;

export const NumberWrapper = styled.div`
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: pink;
`;
export const Number = styled.span`
  color: white;
`;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Container>
        <NumberWrapper>
          <Number>1</Number>
        </NumberWrapper>
        <NumberWrapper>
          <Number>2</Number>
        </NumberWrapper>
        <span>Percentage</span>
        <LineWithPercentage />
        <NumberWrapper>
          <Number>3</Number>
        </NumberWrapper>
      </Container>
      <br />
      <br />
      <Flex>
        <NumberWrapper>
          <Number>1</Number>
        </NumberWrapper>
        <NumberWrapper>
          <Number>2</Number>
        </NumberWrapper>
        <span>Px</span>
        <LineWithPX />
        <NumberWrapper>
          <Number>3</Number>
        </NumberWrapper>
      </Flex>
    </>
  );
}
```

Is there any good idea for this issue?

I also added codesandbox link.
https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-ptolemy-pbq4uh?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I used **grid-auto-flow: column;** but because of this property, the width of the child tag cannot work well.

You were was on the right way, but to get the same result as with **Flexbox** you need to:

Container style

1. Remove `place-content: center;`
2. Set `grid-auto-columns: min-content;`
3. Add `grid-auto-flow: column;`

```css
export const Container = styled.div`
  width: 375px;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: min-content; /* changed */
  grid-auto-flow: column; /* new line */
  /* place-content: center; */ /* remove */
  align-items: center;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
`;
```

After that we get other problem with the **span** line, because we have set `grid-auto-columns: min-content;` and all chidren elements should stack in one line with their own absolute width, but **LineWithPercentage** style has relative width. To fix this, we use calc() function, where we take width **375px** from the **Container** style of  and multiply by **0.42** (42%).

```css
export const LineWithPercentage = styled.div`
  width: calc(375px * 0.42); /* 42% */
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
`;
```

[image: Edit dazziling-code]

Comment: Wow.. you are my life saver. Thanks for your tips! In my case, I need to use max-content then the title can stretch enough. I had to remove `place-content: center` haha... By the way, can I use calc with percentage in grid environment? I'm searching and applying some codes but still the solution is not found yet.

Comment: Yes, you can use calc with percentage, but be aware that if the parent element has a relative grid and the child element (a node without image or text inside) has a relative width and height, child might be collapsed. That's why i used the calc function in **LineWithPercentage**.

Comment: Sure thing! I thought I already click the accept but I just voted for you. haha! Have a great day! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use grid-template-columns to define how many columns you want.
Here, we are using three columns layout (grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr)) to align three things side by side. And text-align: center to center the whole grid inside the container.

```
export const Container = styled.div`
  width: 375px;
  text-align: center;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  align-items: center;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
`;
```

Comment: I edited my code to be more specific. Thanks for your answer but when I tried your solution, the 1fr make each column with the same width.

Comment: You can use grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 3fr; The more the fr the more it takes space.